# Proof of Theorem 15.6 in Matsumura

Tags: commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

This is part of proof of Theorem 15.6 in Matsumura's Commutative Ring theory. I have question on why the inequality
$$\dim C_{M}\leq h+d$$
holds, where $h$ is height of an ideal $JC_{M}$ and $d = \dim C_{M}/JC_{M}$. (Definitely, the other inequality $\dim C_{M}\geq \operatorname{ht}(JC_{M})+\dim (C_{M}/JC_{M}) = h+d$ should hold, but I don't understand how the author can use the reversed inequality.)

To understand the assumptions on the inequality, let $A$ be a Noetherian ring. Suppose that a finitely generated $A$-algebra $B$ exists, and it is an integral domain which is not catenary. Then,

> Write $\mathfrak{p}$ for the kernel of the homomorphism $A \longrightarrow B$. There exist prime ideals $P$ and $Q$ of $B$ such that
> $$
> P \subset Q, \quad \operatorname{ht}(Q / P)=d \quad \text { but } \quad \text { ht } Q>\operatorname{ht} P+d
> $$
> We write $h=$ ht $P$, choose $a_{1}, \ldots, a_{h} \in P$ such that $\operatorname{ht}\left(a_{1}, \ldots, a_{h}\right)=h$, and set $I=\left(a_{1}, \ldots, a_{h}\right)$, so that $P$ is a minimal prime divisor of $I$. Let
> $$
> I=\mathfrak{q}_{1} \cap \cdots \cap \mathfrak{q}_{r}
> $$
> be a shortest primary decomposition of $I$, with $P$ the minimal prime divisor of $\mathfrak{q}_{1}$. Then for $b \in Q \mathfrak{q}_{2} \ldots \mathrm{q}_{r}-P$ we have
> $$
> I: b^{v} B=q_{1} \quad \text { for } \quad v=1,2, \ldots
> $$
> We set $y_{i}=a_{i} / b$ for $1 \leqslant i \leqslant h$
> $$
> C=B\left[y_{1}, \ldots, y_{h}\right], \quad J=\left(y_{1}, \ldots, y_{h}\right) C \text { and } M=J+Q C=J+Q
> $$
> Every element of $C$ can be written in the form $u / b^{k}$ for suitable $k$, with $u \in(I+b B)^{k}$, so that if $z \in J \cap B$ then $z b^{v} \in I$ holds for sufficiently large
> v. Hence $z \in I: b^{v}=\mathfrak{q}_{1} .$ The converse inclusion $\mathfrak{q}_{1} \subset J \cap B$ is obvious, hence $J \cap B=q_{1} .$ Thus
> $$
> \begin{array}{l}
> M \cap B=(J+Q) \cap B=(J \cap B)+Q=Q, \\
> C / J \simeq B / \mathfrak{q}_{1} \text { and } C / M \simeq B / Q .
> \end{array}
> $$
> Therefore, $C_{M} / J C_{M}=B_{Q} / \mathfrak{q}_{1} B_{Q}$ is a $d$ -dimensional local ring, and $J$ is generated by $h$ elements, so that
> $$
> \text { ht } M=\operatorname{dim} C_{M} \leqslant h+d<\operatorname{ht} Q
> $$

The problematic one is this last inequality. Since chain of prime ideals containing $J$ is strictly contained in the collection of all chain of prime ideals, thus I'm worry about the case when the inequality $\dim C_{M} \geq \operatorname{ht}JC_{M}+\dim C_{M}/JC_{M}$ is strict. Any hints will be appreciated!

Comment: How do you know that $\operatorname{ht}(JC_{M})=h$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following result:

> Let $R$ be a noetherian local ring and $r_1,\dots,r_h\in R$ non-invertible elements. Then $\dim R/(r_1,\dots,r_h)\ge\dim R-h$.

This follows readily from Kaplansky, *Commutative Rings*, Theorem 154.

Comment: In fact, we have $$h+\dim R/(r_1,\dots,r_h)\ge\dim R\ge\mathrm{ht}(r_1,\dots,r_h)+\dim R/(r_1,\dots,r_h).$$ It seems that you thought that in the proof $\mathrm{ht}(r_1,\dots,r_h)=h$, which is not necessarily true.

Comment: Thank you very much! And, you right; height of $JC_{M}$ may not equal to the number of its generator.